# Cannot substract the total price in shopping cart but I get the correct price when the page is been refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building an e-commerece site with two pages and two Javascript files i.e:(index.html, cart.html, apps.js and cart.js).  How do I subtract the total price that I had from the shopping cart (cart.html) when the remove button has been clicked?

This is my code:

```
// cart functionality
table.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('fa-close')) {
        let removeItem = event.target;
        console.log('df', removeItem);
        let id = removeItem.dataset.id;
        console.log(id);
        table.removeChild(removeItem.parentElement.parentElement);

        var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || {}; //fetch cart from storage
      
        var items = obj || []; //get the products
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { //loop over the collection
            if (items[i].id === id) { //see if ids match
                items.splice(i, 1); //remove item from array
                break; //exit loop
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj)); //set item back into storage

        //decreasing the cart length
        var cal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        if (cal.length != 0) {
            cart_n.innerHTML = `[${cal.length}]`;
        } else {
            cart_n.innerHTML = '';
        }
          
        //subtractTotal cart
        cal.find(item => {
            tempTotal = 0;
            tempTotal = item.price * item.id
        })
        row.innerHTML = tempTotal;
    }
   
});
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue? Are you receiving any errors in console? You're also using `.find` when it seems you should be using `.forEach`, you're setting `tempTotal` to 0 on every iteration within that loop so the new value will only be the last one in the loop. You're multiplying the `price` by the `id` as well that doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in console..please that multiply sign there is a mistake but minus sign is what I wrote in my code

Comment: I think my issues is that of looping the array, because if I click on remove button it gives me wrong total but when I refresh the page it will now calculate the correct total.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few comments in the code below based on what I believe you're trying to accomplish.

```js
// cart functionality
table.addEventListener("click", event => { 
    // we can first check if the element does NOT (!) contain the class
    // this means you don't need to wrap the remainder of the code
    // as it will return early when the condition isn't met
    if(!event.target.classList.contains('fa-close')){
        return;
    }

    let removeItem = event.target;
    console.log('df', removeItem);


    let id = removeItem.dataset.id;
    console.log(id);

    table.removeChild(removeItem.parentElement.parentElement);
    
    // should you be setting `obj` to `{}` here? (when it doesn't exist)
    // you can't loop over an object the same way you loop over any array
    // it looks like you should instead set it to `[]`
    let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || {}; //fetch cart from storage
    
    let items = obj || []; //get the products
    for(let i = 0;i < items.length;i++) { //loop over the collection
        if (items[i].id === id) { //see if ids match
            items.splice(i, 1); //remove item from array
            break; //exit loop
        }
    }

    // you didn't modify `obj` in the previous loop, only `items`
    // should you instead set this to `items` instead of `obj`?
    // if the data exists in localStorage than you would be modifying
    // `obj` directly but in the case it doesn't yet exist
    // you will be returning a `{}` which cannot be looped over
    // the same way you have above
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj)); //set item back into storage

    // decreasing the cart length
    let cal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    if(cal.length !== 0){
        cart_n.innerHTML = `[${cal.length}]`;
    }else{
        cart_n.innerHTML = '';
    }
    
    // define tempTotal outside of the loop
    let tempTotal = 0;
      
    //subtractTotal cart
    cal.find(item => {
        // increment tempTotal by the price using `+=`
        // I removed the `* item.id` as it doesn't make
        // sense multiplying the `price` by the `id`
        tempTotal += item.price;

        // if the item has a `quantity` property
        // you would use this code instead of the line above
        tempTotal += item.price * item.quantity;
    });

    row.innerHTML = tempTotal;
});
```

Comment: One more thing, please can you help me to write a function that will update the local storage for cart